# Decryption of a file using fernet module in python

Tags: python, encryption, cryptography, python-cryptography, fernet

```
 def encrypt(self):
        if not os.path.exists(self.filename):
            raise Exception('File does not exist!')

        # Generate a random salt
        salt = Fernet.generate_key()

        # Calculate the HMAC of the salt using the key
        hmac_digest = hmac.new(self.key, salt, hashlib.sha256).digest()

        # Encrypt the data with the salt and key
        fernet = Fernet(salt + self.key)
        with open(self.filename, 'rb') as file:
            file_data = file.read()
        encrypted_data = fernet.encrypt(file_data)

        # Write the encrypted data to the file
        with open(self.filename, 'wb') as file:
            file.write(encrypted_data)

     

 def decrypt(self):
        if not os.path.exists(self.filename):
            raise Exception('File does not exist!')

        # Read the salt and HMAC digest from the separate file
        with open(self.filename + '.salt', 'rb') as file:
                k_sz = Fernet.key_size
                salt = file.read(k_sz)
                hmac_digest = file.read(hashlib.sha256().digest_size)
```

here in the decrypt function i am trying to get the salt and hmac value stored in the encrypted file. But receiving the error

```
 File "C:\python programs\test2.py", line 61, in decrypt
    k_sz = Fernet.key_size
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: type object 'Fernet' has no attribute 'key_size'
```

i have tried .KEY_SIZE and Fernet(key=None).key_size then it says key value as none not expected

Comment: What size did you use when you created the salt in the encryption code? In any case, looking through the `Fernet` source code I didn't see any method or property to retrieve the key size, and key size is hard coded throughout.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk, I have added the encryption function, using Fernet default function to generate the salt key

Comment: Fernet is really easy to use, but you are making it harder on yourself. Fernet includes a MAC computation that is verified upon decryption, so you don't have to do it yourself and you should not try to. You are also using the `generate_key()` function to generate a salt. This should work, but it just conflates keys are salts which is a bad idea. There are two examples in the Fernet documentation that should cover almost all cases. Use the one that matches your scenario.

Comment: [Example 1](https://cryptography.io/en/latest/) is used when you let Fernet generate the key. [Example 2](https://cryptography.io/en/latest/fernet/#using-passwords-with-fernet) is when you are using a password or pass phrase to generate the key.